# Oracle Procedure compile error

Tags: oracle, procedure

Bellow is my procedure.

```
create or replace procedure my_log (action in varchar2, message in varchar2 )
is

begin
  Insert into my_log_table (ACTION, MESSAGE, EVENT_DATE)
  values (action, message, sysdate);
  commit;
end;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CUSTOMER_INCREMENTAL" ()
IS   
   err_num NUMBER;
   err_msg VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    my_log ('Start','My message');
  INSERT INTO NDB_AML_CUSTOMER 
(ID, TITLE,...)
  SELECT ID, TITLE,... 
FROM NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW
WHERE DATE_TIME > (SELECT RUN_DATE FROM CHECK_POINT WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW');

  UPDATE CHECK_POINT SET RUN_DATE = SYSDATE WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW';

  COMMIT;
  my_log ('End','My message');
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
err_num := SQLCODE;
err_msg := SQLERRM;
my_log ('Error' , errnum ||' - ' || err_msg);
 END;
/
```

When I compile it gives the error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:   current delete exists prior. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `()` if function or procedure has no parameters.

Comment: Without brackets it compile but during execution it tells  Customer Incremental must be declared

Comment: execute Customer Incremental ();

Comment: I executed CUSTOMER_INCREMENTAL but it tells PLS-00201: identifier 'CUSTOMER_INCREMENTAL' must be declared